# Ubuntu does not boot after Windows 10 was installed – Error reading block on Microsoft System Reserved Partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, windows-10, fsck

I had Ubuntu and Fedora running in dual boot but I had to install Windows 10 to stop my laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 330-15ARR) from freezing constantly at random in both distros. This points to a video driver issue in linux kernels at the moment.

I can boot into Fedora with no problem. However, Ubuntu fails to boot (though the Ubuntu bootloader and its partition seem intact) with the following error:

```
Error reading block 17334271 (Invalid argument)

/dev/sda3: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options)

fsck exited with status code 4

The root filesystem on /dev/sda3 requires manual fsck
```

The partition `/dev/sda3` is the Microsoft System Reserved Partition (MSRP) which has been formatted as Ext4 by the Windows installer (which is a mystery to me, really).

This is the output from `sudo fdisk -l` (from Fedora):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10SPZX-24Z
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B4736AF6-9343-441C-8149-2A047E71AA32

Device          Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048  209717247 209715200  100G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2   209717248  314574847 104857600   50G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   314574848  314607615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4   314607616  523217697 208610082 99.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   523218944  524287999   1069056  522M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6   782157824 1222559743 440401920  210G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  1222559744 1851705343 629145600  300G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  1851705344 1935591423  83886080   40G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  1935591424 1937688575   2097152    1G EFI System
/dev/sda10 1937688576 1953523711  15835136  7.6G Linux swap
```

Partitions are now set in order probably through Windows updates. Everything was fine with Ubuntu until the Windows installation a week before today.

I am afraid of running the `fsck` utility using an Ubuntu live USB simply because it will detect errors and attempt a fix, which might break the Windows installation (which, by the way, is working fine).

I have tried to mount the offending MSRP partition but got this error:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt

mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

So, my questions are:

1. Should I attempt to reinstall Ubuntu on `/dev/sda1` or is `fsck` required to clean up the MSRP?
2. Should I just go with the flow and do nothing?
3. Should I install some other linux distro (openSUSE, maybe) on `/dev/sda1` and then install Ubuntu again after that in the available space?

Output of `gdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: WDC WD10SPZX-24Z
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): B4736AF6-9343-441C-8149-2A047E71AA32
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 257874507 sectors (123.0 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048       209717247   100.0 GiB   8300  
   2       209717248       314574847   50.0 GiB    8300  
   3       314574848       314607615   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   4       314607616       523217697   99.5 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   5       523218944       524287999   522.0 MiB   2700  
   6       782157824      1222559743   210.0 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   7      1222559744      1851705343   300.0 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   8      1851705344      1935591423   40.0 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   9      1935591424      1937688575   1024.0 MiB  EF00  EFI System Partition
  10      1937688576      1953523711   7.6 GiB     8200  Linux swap
```

Comment: Adding/installing an OS to try to fix problem in another OS just gives more problems.  17MBs seem to be small for any working partition.  Windows does not read ext4(or any Linux file systems) so something weird happen if Windows formatted to ext4(it can't).  Should google your freezing problem to find answers.  Can reinstall Ubuntu on it's partition, but data lost is possible, don't format, just reinstall.

Comment: Microsoft reserved is a 128MB unformatted partition and must be before first NTFS partition, usually just before partition that is c: "drive". It sounds more like another partition got reset to the GUID code that is Microsoft reserved.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition Post this: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` if drive is sda or use your drive.

Comment: I'll post the contents of sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda tomorrow.